# xdg-open without an option to “remember”

Tags: google-chrome, 19.04

On a brand new Ubuntu 19.04, the latest chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit) refuses to remember my selection. I'm trying to open a zoom URL, I'm getting the [Open xdg-open?] and just the action buttons without the checkbox to store my selection. I have removed `~/.config/google-chrome` options in order to reset it but still same behavior

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution. I've two machines with the same debian on and one is prompting without the option to remember too.

Comment: Well.. I know why it does that but I haven't found a solution. It's Google's stupidity I guess. They have disabled the checkbox to store your selection in version 77: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14193532?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Create following path and file:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/
sudo touch /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed/managed_policies.json
```

Open permissions for this file:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed
```

By default adding following content to this file should add the checkbox to remember your choice:

```
{
    "ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox": true
}
```

This worked for all external website for me. For custom link, you may need to add those links to the whitelist:

```
{
    "ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox": true,
    "URLWhitelist": [
        "telnet://*",
        "rvlink://*"
    ]
}
```

Same question on different community: [Stop chrome from prompting when running external URL handler?](https://superuser.com/questions/1524249/stop-chrome-from-prompting-when-running-external-url-handler/1572925#1572925)

Comment: Probably works only for `https` sites?